# Android popupwindow outsidetouchable and ontouch listener

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Hi I have a popupwindow on my project. 
I want these;

The outside of popupwindow will be touchable and
The popupwindow will be dissmiss when clik on popupwindow.

Actualy I want to use this like

Full screen back button. 
I have a full screen button. it makes some components to full screen.
I want to put a  popup button full go back from fullscreen view.

How can I do this ?

Sorry for bad english.
Thanks...

Comment: You want to hide the pop up upon clicking outside of it?

Comment: I solve using button in framelayout.
Thanks for answers.